# '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' in Python

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to create a new variable in dataframe Call08q1_09q1 by adding two float variable

```
Call08q1_09q1['MBS']=Call08q1_09q1['RCFD8639']+Call08q1_09q1['RCFD2170']
```

the error below shows up:

'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' in Python

However, I don't have string in my dataframe.

```
Call08q1_09q1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 39675 entries, 0 to 39674
Data columns (total 20 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------    --------------  -----  
 0   RSSD9001  39675 non-null  float64
 1   RSSD9999  39675 non-null  float64
 2   RCFD2170  39673 non-null  float64
 3   RCFD8639  38166 non-null  float64
 4   RCFD8641  38166 non-null  float64
 5   RCFD8639  38166 non-null  float64
 6   RCFD0211  38166 non-null  float64
 7   RCFD1287  38166 non-null  float64
 8   RCON3531  1107 non-null   float64
 9   RCFD1289  38166 non-null  float64
 10  RCFD1294  38166 non-null  float64
 11  RCFD1293  38166 non-null  float64
 12  RCFD1298  38166 non-null  float64
 13  RCON3532  1111 non-null   float64
 14  RCFD3210  38443 non-null  float64
 15  RIAD4230  38398 non-null  float64
 16  RIAD4340  38441 non-null  float64
 17  RCFD2122  39644 non-null  float64
 18  RCFD2125  249 non-null    float64
 19  RCFD1600  52 non-null     float64
dtypes: float64(20)
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Try to replace NaN Values with Zero. (`fillna(0)`)

Comment: Clearly, *something* is being interpreted as a string. What debugging have you attempted?

Comment: the same problem still shows up after I fill missing value with 0. However, the original dataframe is sas format.  Could it be the problem? ```Call08q1_09q1 = pd.read_sas('file, format = 'sas7bdat')```

Answer (score 0):

You have loads of nulls in your columns as the printout tells you. How are those represented? Can you add these nulls with ints? I suggest you debug by inspecting these null values and taking appropriate action to fill them, drop them, or otherwise transform them into something useful.

Comment: I've tried drop null values, the same problem still shows up.

Answer (score 0):

The error has not occured in the line of code below since this one does not contain any comparison operator `(<, >, ..)`.

```
Call08q1_09q1['MBS']= Call08q1_09q1['RCFD8639'] + Call08q1_09q1['RCFD2170']
```

The error has for sure occured in a line where you try to compare a string with a number (int) like the scenario below :

```
s="1"
n= 3
s < n
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 3
      1 s="1"
      2 n= 3
----> 3 s<n

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

To fix that you need to cast the string as a number :

```
int(s) < n
#True
```